# If $f(z)= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nz^n$ has radius of convergence 1 and if $c_n\geq 0$ for each $n$, then $f$ is not analytic at 1.

Tags: complex-analysis

**My Attempt:**

Assume that $f$ analytic at $1$ Then by definition of analytic function $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $1$ then we have
$$\lim\limits_{z\to 1} f(z)=f(1)$$ or $$\lim\limits_{z\to 1, |z|<1} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nz^n= \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty c_n=f(1)<\infty$$ But $c_n\geq 0$, deduce $c_n\rightarrow 0$, which contradicts to the condition that radius of convergence is 1 (this means $\lim\sup(|c_n|^\frac{1}{n})=1)$. Therefore our assumption is false and we conclude that $f$ is not analytic.

Am I correct? Thanks.

Comment: You can still have $c_n \to 0$ while $|c_n|^{\frac{1}{n}} \to 1$, for example $c_n = \frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. $c_n \to 0$ does not contradict that the radius of convergence is $1$. For example look at $c_n=1/n$.

What you have to prove is a heavy theorem: Pringsheim's Theorem

https://sunlimingbit.wordpress.com/2012/01/24/pringsheim-theorem/

Comment: I see, didn't know or learn about it yet, but I think I can follow the proof, Thanks